# How can I call method in setState() (Flutter)?

Tags: flutter

I tried to call a method in `setState()` for updating data.
But I got this error:

```
There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: 3. 
Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value
'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart':
Failed assertion: line 915 pos 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null ||
  items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) { return item.value == value;
}).length == 1'
```

[image]

I just want to update a data. because I fetch my data only on initState.

And this is my code about it.

```
Future<String> getProductData() async {
String url = 'http://172.30.1.6/product.php?id='+_customerSelection;
var res = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
var resBody = json.decode(res.body);

  setState((){
  productData = resBody;
});

print(url);

return "Success";
}

final customers = Container(
  child: Row(
    children: [
      Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:5),
            child: Text('Customer :')
          )
        ],
      ),
      Row(
        children: <Widget>[Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:5),
            child: new DropdownButton(
              value: _customerSelection,
              items: customerData.map((product) {
                return new DropdownMenuItem(
                    value: product["CustomerID"].toString(),
                    child: new Text(product["CustomerName"]!)
                );
              }).toList(),
              onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                setState(() {
                  _customerSelection = newValue!;
                  getProductData();
                });
              },
              hint: Text('Customer'),
            )
        ),
        ],
      )
    ],
  )
);
```

So I just want to call method using setState()

Comment: Can you please add JSON response as well

Comment: Can you show us where `customerData` is initialized?

Comment: @AnandaPramono it is on class _FirstAppState extends State<FirstApp> {

  List productData = [];
  List customerData =[];

Comment: Maybe its because yout `customerData` dont have any value in it, that why it gives that error

Comment: @mofidulislam part of Json is this : [{"CustomerID":"64","CustomerName":"KFM"},{"CustomerID":"2","CustomerName":"Ghana"}.

Comment: @anandaPramono Ah I`m so sorry for missing some information.  CustomerData is getting data from method getCustomerData(). it is same logic as getProductData(). I mean when I change dropdown menu item, this error occur.

Comment: _customerSelection is null or is not in response of api response or there is duplicate field of customer ID

Comment: If I remove method in here, there is no error. onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                setState(() {
                  _customerSelection = newValue!;
                  //getProductData();
                });

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.